# Can we define the Lebesgue measure $\mu:\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R})\to[0,\infty]$ using Carathéodory's Extension Theorem?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, alternative-proof

David Williams constructs the Lebesgue measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb{R}$ (excerpt at the end of the post) by first defining $\mu$ on an algebra $\Sigma_0$, and then using Carathéodory's Extension Theorem (excerpt also at the end) to extend $\mu$ into $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})=\{\text{Borel sets}\}$. The resulting function is ***not*** defined on $\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R})=\{\text{Carathéodory measurable sets}\}$, but rather it is defined on a proper subset of it.

---

***Can we define the Lebesgue measure $\mu:\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R})\to[0,\infty]$ using Carathéodory's Extension Theorem?*** The goal, of course, if to define the Lebesgue measure (with $\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R})$ as its domain) while following Williams' outline of its construction.

This could be done, for example, by finding a suitable algebra $\Sigma_0$ such that $\sigma(\Sigma_0)=\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R})$.

---

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes. I am used to the Lebesgue measure being defined on the Caratheodory measurable sets, as generated by the standard outer measure

Comment: @FShrike the construction I know which uses an outer measures $\mu^*$ does not use Caràtheodory's Extension Theorem (it doesn't need to, since the theorem _extends_ the domain of the function, but the domain of $\mu^*$ is already larger than $\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R})$).

Comment: Not the extension theorem per se. Just, the Lebesgue algebra is typically taken to be that of all Caratheodory measurable sets w.r.t the standard $\mu^\ast:\mathcal{P}(\Bbb R^n)\to[0,\infty]$

Comment: @FShrike yes, the measure $\mu$ is usually defined on $\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R})$, hence the question (: